# Flutter: How to draw a stickie only on the top right side of the container

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

[this image shows the current result i have, and i want it on the top right instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLeOh.png)I have a class that draws a stickie, and this stickie is used to display some text content to the user, and this code works very fine but the i want to draw the stickie on the top right instead.

here i have a code

```dart
import 'dart:math' show pi;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'
    show
        Alignment,
        BuildContext,
        Canvas,
        Center,
        Color,
        Colors,
        CustomPaint,
        CustomPainter,
        Paint,
        Path,
        RadialGradient,
        Rect,
        Size,
        StatelessWidget,
        Transform,
        Widget;

class StickyNote extends StatelessWidget {
  const StickyNote({
    required this.color,
    required this.child,
    super.key,
  });

  final Widget child;
  final Color color;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Transform.rotate(
        angle: 0.01 * pi,
        child: CustomPaint(
          painter: _StickyNotePainter(color: color),
          child: Center(child: child),
        ),
      );
}

class _StickyNotePainter extends CustomPainter {
  _StickyNotePainter({required this.color});

  Color color;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    _drawShadow(size, canvas);
    Paint gradientPaint = _createGradientPaint(size);
    _drawNote(size, canvas, gradientPaint);
  }

  void _drawNote(Size size, Canvas canvas, Paint gradientPaint) {
    Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);

    double foldAmount = 0.12;
    path.lineTo(size.width * 3 / 4, size.height);

    path.quadraticBezierTo(
      size.width * foldAmount * 2,
      size.height,
      size.width * foldAmount,
      size.height - (size.height * foldAmount),
    );
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
      0,
      size.height - (size.height * foldAmount * 1.5),
      0,
      size.height / 4,
    );
    path.lineTo(0, 0);

    canvas.drawPath(path, gradientPaint);
  }

  Paint _createGradientPaint(Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint();

    Color brighten(Color c, [int percent = 30]) {
      double p = percent / 100;
      return Color.fromARGB(
        c.alpha,
        c.red + ((255 - c.red) * p).round(),
        c.green + ((255 - c.green) * p).round(),
        c.blue + ((255 - c.blue) * p).round(),
      );
    }

    Rect rect = Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    RadialGradient gradient = RadialGradient(
      colors: <Color>[brighten(color), color],
      radius: 1.0,
      stops: const <double>[0.5, 1.0],
      center: Alignment.bottomLeft,
    );
    paint.shader = gradient.createShader(rect);
    return paint;
  }

  void _drawShadow(Size size, Canvas canvas) {
    Rect rect = Rect.fromLTWH(12, 12, size.width - 24, size.height - 24);
    Path path = Path();
    path.addRect(rect);
    canvas.drawShadow(path, Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7), 12.0, true);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => oldDelegate != this;
}
```

this code draws a stickie on the bottom left.  and i want the stickie on the top right instead. anyway this code is only used in a SizedBox (with fixed height and width) don't forget that.